# Managing Object Change Notification Channels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

If I subscribe to an object change notification channel using the [watchAll](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/watchAll) endpoint of the Google Cloud Storage JSON API, is there a place in the Google Cloud Console for me to manage these channels?

Comment: Hi @AviatingFotographer I have provided an answer below. Please check and let me know if the below suggestions were helpful

Comment: Please don't use object change notification. You should use cloud pubsub instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_How)

> Only one type of notification channel, a web hook, is currently supported.

Also as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#unsupported) on how to configure notification channels by using the Google Cloud console

> If your preferred notification channel isn't supported, consider creating a pipeline that relies on sending your notifications to Pub/Sub. For a Python example that uses Flask, see [Creating custom notifications with Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/operations/write-and-deploy-cloud-monitoring-alert-notifications-to-third-party-services). For other examples, see the [cloud-alerting-notification-forwarding Git repository](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/cloud-alerting-notification-forwarding).